# How can I compare two strings to find the number of characters that match in R, using substitution distance?

Tags: r, string-comparison, edit-distance, string-substitution

In R, I have two character vectors, a and b.

```
a <- c("abcdefg", "hijklmnop", "qrstuvwxyz")
b <- c("abXdeXg", "hiXklXnoX", "Xrstuvwxyz")
```

I want a function that counts the character mismatches between each element of a and the corresponding element of b. Using the example above, such a function should return `c(2,3,1)`. There is no need to align the strings.
I need to compare each pair of strings character-by-character and count matches and/or mismatches in each pair. Does any such function exist in R?

Or, to ask the question in another way, is there a function to give me the ***edit distance*** between two strings, where the only allowed operation is substitution (ignore insertions or deletions)?

Comment: Strictly that's just ***substitution distance***, not full ***edit distance***.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using some `mapply` fun:

```
mapply(function(x,y) sum(x!=y),strsplit(a,""),strsplit(b,""))
#[1] 2 3 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't do what I asked. It happens to give the correct answer on my example, but it would not work if the strings had repeated letters. For example, consider `a <- "aaaaaaa"; b <- "aaaXaaa"`. Your code would return 6 mismatches when the correct answer is 1.

Comment: @RyanThompson - Okay - have adjusted the answer to account for repeats.

Comment: For clarity I'd rename the vars and the fn: `substitution_distance <- function(s1,s2) { mapply(function(c1,c2) sum(c1!=c2), strsplit(s1,''), strsplit(s2,'')) }`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `adist` which Compute the approximate string distance between character vectors:

```
mapply(adist,a,b)
abcdefg  hijklmnop qrstuvwxyz 
     2          3          1
```

Comment: The two solutions aren't totally interchangeable, try: `a <- c("cdefgba", "hijklmnop", "qrstuvwxyz")`, my solution gives `c(7,3,1)` while `adist` gives `c(6,3,1)`

Comment: This answer allows indels, while I'm just asking for a character-by-character comparison.